# grep exact integer match

Tags: bash, unix

```
read -p "Please enter ID: " staffID 
id=$(grep -w "$staffID" record | cut -d ":" -f1 | sort -u );
echo $id
```

I have some issues with trying to grep the correct value from a file.

The following is stored in the record file.

```
12:Griffin:Peter:13:14:16
14:Griffin:Meg:19:19:10
10:Griffin:Loi:19:20:20
130:Griffin:Stewie:19:19:19
13:Wayne:Bruce:19:20:2
```

My first column stores the id which is always unique and is what I am looking for in grep. With the code above, I only want to find the unique ID which is entered by a user and is displayed on screen but my echo produces a blank value if I enter an ID of 13 when it should produce 13 obviously. Any ideas which would solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please enter ID: " staffID

#your code was commented out
#id=$(grep -w "$staffID" record | cut -d ":" -f1 | sort -u );

id=$(grep -oP "^${staffID}(?=:)" record)
line=$(grep "^${staffID}:" record)

echo $id #use this line if you just want ID 
echo $line #use this line if you want the line with given ID
```

see comments in codes

**Note** 
I don't know the exact requirement, but I suggest that before do grep, check user input, if they inputted a valid id `([0-9]+)` maybe? Because user could input `.*`

Comment: Awesome thanks very much, works perfectly! What do the options -oP look for in grep?

Comment: @user1983064 for the options -o: display only the matched part. -P using perl regex.

Comment: Ah ok. I have a similar problem now with another feature of my code, is there a way I could delete a line by exact id only? I've tried using sed but to no avail :(

Comment: @user1983064 yes you can `sed -i "/^${staffID}:/d" record` try it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems adding a ^ to grep should solve your problem.

```
    read -p "Please enter ID: " staffID
    [[ "$staffID" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { echo "Enter only Numbers. Aborting" ; exit 2 ;  }
    id=$(grep -w "^$staffID" record | cut -d ":" -f1 | sort -u );
    if [ "$id" == "" ]; then
            echo "ID : Not found"
    else
            echo $id
    fi
```

I have added a line to check that your input is a valid number.